# How to print data with the same situation in a separate dives through a for loop in flask template

Tags: python, html, templates, for-loop, flask

There is a table like this in my database:

```
-------------------------------------
.  id  .  part  .      text         .
-------------------------------------
.  1   .   1    .  different text   .
.  2   .   1    .  different text   .
.  3   .   1    .  different text   .
.  4   .   1    .  different text   .
.  5   .   2    .  different text   .
.  6   .   2    .  different text   .
.  7   .   3    .  different text   .
.  8   .   3    .  different text   .
.  9   .   3    .  different text   .
.  10  .   3    .  different text   .
.  11  .   3    .  different text   .
.  12  .   4    .  different text   .
.  13  .   4    .  different text   .
.  14  .   5    .  different text   .
.  15  .   5    .  different text   .
-------------------------------------
```

In app.py, `result2` will contain something like this: (a list of tuple)

> ((1, 1, 'text'), (2, 1, 'text'), (3, 1, 'text'), (4, 1, 'text'), (5, 2, 'text'), (6, 2, 'text'), (7, 3, 'text'), (8, 3, 'text'), etc..)

```
@app.route('/shop/<data>')
def shop(data):
    db =MySQLdb.connect("localhost","myusername","mypassword","mydbname" )

   cursor = db.cursor()
   cursor2 = db.cursor()


   query_string = "SELECT * from p_div_chest1"
   query_string2 = "SELECT * from p_div_content1"


   cursor.execute(query_string)
   cursor2.execute(query_string2)


   result = cursor.fetchall()
   result2 = cursor2.fetchall()

   db.close()
   return render_template('shop.html', result=result, result2=result2)
```

Now in shop.html I want to have a for loop to print all text with their same `part` numbers in separate `<div></div>` tag.

For example all text where their `part` numbers is 1 should be printed in a separate `div`.

And all text with `part` number 2 should go to next separate `div` tag.

For example:

It's like that I select * from the table `where part = 1` and print in the first `div` tag. The output would look like:

```
--------------------
-  different text  -
-  different text  -
-  different text  -
-  different text  -
--------------------
```

and next I select * from the table `where part = 2` and print in the first `div` tag. The output would look like:

```
--------------------
-  different text  -
-  different text  -
--------------------
```

shop.html is like this for now:

```
{% for each in result2 %}
    {{ each }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to put something like `{%if each.1 == 1 %}` in that for loop to check `each.1` every thime, and if `each.1 == 1`, for loop starts to print texts in the first div and go on until `each.1 == 2`, then close last div tag and open the next div tag to print all texts that are equal to `each.1 == 2` and move on ....

Hope my explanation helps more.

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve... can you give sample how your template will look like ?

Comment: @daniee, why did you delete your answers?!

Comment: i was making some little modification...it's back now

Answer (score 0):

i'll suggest you keep your template as clean as possible, and put all the logic in your view, first use itertools.groupby to group the elements into seperate lists to make it easier for printing, the elements in result2 are already sorted so you don't need to sort them again, if they're not sorted groupby won't work

```
from itertools import groupby
x = [(1, 1, 'text'), (2, 1, 'text'), (3, 1, 'text'), (4, 1, 'text'), (5, 2, 'text'), (6, 2, 'text'), (7, 3, 'text'), (8, 3, 'text')]

result2 = [list(value) for key, value in groupby(x, lambda y: y[1])]
```

with raw python code, we have this

```
for elems in result:
    print('<div>')
    for elem in elems:
        print(elem)

    print('</div>')
```

Output

```
<div>
(1, 1, 'text')
(2, 1, 'text')
(3, 1, 'text')
(4, 1, 'text')
</div>
<div>
(5, 2, 'text')
(6, 2, 'text')
</div>
<div>
(7, 3, 'text')
(8, 3, 'text')
</div>
```

so translating that to jinja we have this

```
{% for elems in result2 %}
    <div>
    {% for elem in elems %}
        {{ elem }}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: could you please explaine this line for me please? `result2 = [list(value) for key, value in groupby(x, lambda y: y[1])]`. It is not clear for me. Thank you.

Comment: and here in this line `x = [(1, 1, 'text'), (2, 1, 'text'), (3, 1, 'text'), (4, 1, 'text'), (5, 2, 'text'), (6, 2, 'text'), (7, 3, 'text'), (8, 3, 'text')]` we have set data manualy, how i can fill `x` variable from database selecting? I mean if I want to delete that line then where should I edit instead to be that line's alternative?

Comment: Jinja's for/else works differently than Python's. You'd only close the div when `elems` is empty, which would never actually happen. Why wouldn't you just close the tag outside the loop?

Comment: @dim thanks for pointing that out...guess i got carried away with `for`, `else`

Comment: @niloofar in your case change the lambda expression to `lamba y: y.part`, the sql query returns a list of objects not a list of tuples...so basically `itertools.groupby` groups elements in a list based on a particular condition which is the lambda i defined....read the docs https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html

Comment: @daniee, thank you for the explanation. But what about the question I asked about deleting `x` part and edit an other line for `x` line alternative?

Comment: It will raise this error in terminal: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result2' referenced before assignment'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118233/discussion-between-danidee-and-niloofar).