# flask template setting id for divs in a for loop

Tags: python, templates, for-loop, flask

In the html file:

```
{% for elems in result2 %}

        <div style="border:1px solid green;">

        {% for elem in elems %}

            {{ elem }}

        {%endfor%}

        </div><br>

{%endfor%}
```

I want to give `id` to `<div>` and the id should be set to `{{ elem.1 }}`

As you see here, each row will be printed in separate div, so here we would have 3 dives that the id of the first div would be 1 as the `{{ elem.1 }}` of the first row is 1, and ....

```
(1, 1, 'text') (2, 1, 'text') (3, 1, 'text') (4, 1, 'text')

(5, 2, 'text') (6, 2, 'text')

(7, 3, 'text') (8, 3, 'text')
```

but the open div tag comes before printing `{{ elem }}` ro after `{%endfor%}`, so how can I do that?

Comment: this is the same question you posted earlier right ? what about this answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/38564134/3762142

Comment: It seems you have not understand my main question weel. It is different.

Comment: It's a nested for loop. I want to access to element inside the second for loop while I'm in the first loop.

Comment: what is the data structure for result2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could just use `id="{{ elems[0][1] }}"`

Comment: @MadRabbit: is there a reason to mix subscripts with dot notation? Wouldn't it be better to be consistent, e.g., `{{ elems[0][1] }}` or `{{ elems.0.1 }}`.

Comment: @mhawke You're right, there's no reason for that, from a quick glance I thought the `.1` was just a regular attribute for the element.

Answer (score 1):

The data structure being used for `result2` is unclear, but assuming that it is a list of lists of tuples you should be able to reach the second element of the first tuple of each list with `elems.0.1`. In the template:

```
{% for elems in result2 %}
        <div id="{{ elems.0.1 }}"" style="border:1px solid green;">
        {% for elem in elems %}
            {{ elem }}
        {%endfor%}
        </div><br>
{%endfor%}
```

Here I am assuming that `result2` is something like this:

```
>>> result2 = [[(1, 1, 'text'), (2, 1, 'text'), (3, 1, 'text'), (4, 1, 'text')],
           [(5, 2, 'text'), (6, 2, 'text')],
           [(7, 3, 'text'), (8, 3, 'text')]]

>>> print(render_template_string(template, result2=result2))


    <div id="1" style="border:1px solid green;">

            (1, 1, 'text')

            (2, 1, 'text')

            (3, 1, 'text')

            (4, 1, 'text')

    </div><br>

    <div id="2" style="border:1px solid green;">

            (5, 2, 'text')

            (6, 2, 'text')

    </div><br>

    <div id="3" style="border:1px solid green;">

            (7, 3, 'text')

            (8, 3, 'text')

    </div><br>
```